# How are AngularJS and AngularUI related to each other?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I wonder what the relationship between [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org/) and [AngularUI](http://angular-ui.github.com/) is?

A quick look at the contributors' list seems to say that both projects are developed by independent teams.

Does anyone know more about the relationship between these two projects?

What's especially interesting is the question whether things provided by AngularUI will (one day) become merged into AngularJS. This would be extremly useful for things such as [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router).

Anyone know more than me ;-)?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

[AngularUI is an organization](https://github.com/angular-ui) that originally started off as one project to consolidate efforts people were making early on across the entire community to create defacto widgets and directives for AngularJS (like jQueryUI is to jQuery). Although it started off as one project with multiple widget wrappers, it's evolved into an organization with multiple teams and projects with different focuses.

Although we didn't start off with any AngularJS core team members, we have been working very closely with them to improve the AngularJS community and today we have 2 of our team members ([Pete Bacon Darwin](https://github.com/petebacondarwin) & [Pawel Kozlowski](https://github.com/pkozlowski-opensource)) who have been added to the AngularJS core team.

Some of the projects include:

- AngularUI (soon to be broken up into 0-dependency utilities and widget wrappers)
- UI-Bootstrap: A reimplementation of all Bootstrap components in native AngularJS (as per popular demand by both the community and the core team itself)
- UI-Router: An attempt to create defacto solution to complex/nested routing that we hope to eventually get merged into the core
- uiBot (UniBot): IRC bot for the #angularjs channel
- NG-Grid: A SlickGrid-inspired virtual grid solution for AngularJS

We've also been actively talking to [Jim Hoskins](https://github.com/jimrhoskins) (the guy behind [ngmodules.org](http://ngmodules.org/)) to create an AngularJS-based package distribution and organization system/standards for the community as a whole.

Answer (score 17):

Basically AngularJS is the MVC framework itself, while  AngularUI is a bunch of UI components built over Angular. Think of in the same way as [jQuery](http://jquery.com) and [jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/).

There are a few utility directives, like `ui-router`, `ui-keypress` and `ui-event`, but it is mostly about pre-built widgets.

You will see no such widgets in AngularJS project. There is no `tab`, `button`, `calendar` or any other widget. Only the raw directives, resources and tools to allow you to develop anything your project need.

Adding a third related project, while AngularUI uses [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) layout, there is a project from AngularUI team called [UI Bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.com/bootstrap/) that is the implementation of Bootstrap components over AngularJS instead of jQuery.

It is possible that some base directive/service, like `ui-event` or `ui-keypress`, to become part of the project, but there is no plans, at least not explicity plans, to merge both projects due to its nature. In other words, it's hardly possible that the widgets (`ui-calendar`, `ui-button`, `ui-date`) will be merged.